# Python 3: Getting information from list in list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have txt file in Python 3 like this (cities are just examples):

```
Tokyo 0 267 308 211 156 152 216 27 60 70 75
London 267 0 155 314 111 203 101 258 254 199 310
Paris 308 155 0 429 152 315 216 330 295 249 351
Vienna 211 314 429 0 299 116 212 184 271 265 252
Tallinn 156 111 152 299 0 183 129 178 143 97 199
Helsinki 152 203 313 116 183 0 99 126 212 151 193
Stockholm 216 101 216 212 129 99 0 189 252 161 257
Moscow 27 258 330 184 178 126 189 0 87 73 68
Riga 60 254 295 271 143 212 252 87 0 91 71
Melbourne 70 199 249 265 97 151 161 73 91 0 128
Oslo 75 310 351 252 199 193 257 68 71 128 0
```

I want to get program to work like this with an example:

```
Please enter starting point: Paris
Now please enter ending point: Riga
Distance between Paris and Riga is 295 km.
```

I'm fairly new in Python and I don't know how to read distance list in list.
What I managed to do so far:

```
cities = [] 
distances = []

file = open("cities.txt")

for city_info in file:
city_info = city_info.strip()
city = city_info.split()        
cities.append(city[0])

distances2 = []
for dist in city[1:]:
    distances2.append(int(dist))   
distances.append(distances2)

# to check, if lists are good to go

print(distances)
print(cities)

file.close()

amount = len(cities)

for x in range(amount):
    for y in range(amount):
        startpoint = cities[x]
        endpoint = cities[y]
        dist1 = distances[x][y]

    startpoint = input("Enter start point: ").capitalize()
    if startpoint not in cities:
        print("Start point doesn't exist in our database: ", startpoint)
    else:
        endpoint = input("Enter end point: ").capitalize()
        if endpoint not in cities:
            print("Start point doesn't exist in our database: ", endpoint)
        else:
            print("Distance between", startpoint, "and", endpoint, "is", dist1, "kilometers.")
```

As I'm not very competent in Python language, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

For example I want to get distance between cities[1] and cities[4], so it should find distance from distances[1][4].

Comment: Your indention is not correct...

Comment: out of the many bad things in your code the most noticeable is the indentation of stuff coming after the nested for loops, which should be at the same level as the inner for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# reading from file:
with open('cities.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# pre-processing
indices = {line.split()[0]: i for i, line in enumerate(lines)}
distances = [line.split()[1:] for line in lines]

#user input:
start = input("Please enter starting point: ")
end = input("Now please enter ending point: ")

# evaluation:
distance = distances[indices[start]][indices[end]]

# output:
print("Distance between {start} and {end} is {distance} km.".format(**locals()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, not too different from the other answer.

```
cities = {}

with open('cities.txt') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f.read().splitlines()):
        vals = line.split()
        cities[vals[0]] = {'index': i, 'distances': [int(i) for i in vals[1:]]}

startpoint = input("Enter start point: ").capitalize()

if startpoint in cities:
    endpoint = input("Enter end point: ").capitalize()
    if endpoint in cities:
        index = cities[startpoint]['index']
        distance = cities[endpoint]['distances'][index]
        print('The distance from %s to %s is %d' % (startpoint, endpoint, distance))
    else:
        print('city %s does not exist' % endpoint)
else:
    print('city %s does not exist' % startpoint)
```